# Submit event not finishing on some case with JQuery and MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a very strange problem using JQuery. I have a fileupload form where the user can click on 2 buttons: "Save file" or "No picture". The two are calling the same controller that manage if there is a picture or not in the fileupload field.

What is weird is that the controller get's called only in the cases when the fileupload field is empty. If someone has choosen a picture, it just doesnt go in the controller which let me think that the submit is just not working. But my jquery code get's called and always returns true...

Here is the JQuery code which is in the document.ready:

```
$('#ImgForm').on('submit', function () {

        var fileUploader = document.getElementById("fileuploader");
        $(fileUploader).hide();

        var fileUploader = document.getElementById("informations");
        $(fileUploader).show();

        //Create a new image and insert it into the Images div.  Just to be fancy, 
        //we're going to use a "FadeIn" effect from jQuery
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById("Images");
        loadingImg = new Image();
        loadingImg.src = "../../Pictures/ajax-loader.gif";

        //Hide the image before adding to the DOM
        $(loadingImg).hide();
        imgDiv.appendChild(loadingImg);
        //Now fade the image in
        $(loadingImg).fadeIn(500, null);

        return true;
    });
```

Here is the MVC View code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Recipe", FormMethod.Post,
                new
                {
                    enctype = "multipart/form-data",
                    id = "ImgForm",
                    name = "ImgForm",
                    target = "UploadTarget"
                }))
            {
                <div id="fileuploader">
                    <h4>Étape 1: Choisir une photo</h4>
                    <input id="lefile" type="file" style="display:none" name="imageFile" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" />
                    <div class="input-append">
                       <input id="photoCover" class="input-large" type="text" />
                       <a class="btn" onclick="$('input[id=lefile]').click();">Parcourir...</a>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('input[id=lefile]').change(function () {
                            $('#photoCover').val($(this).val());
                        }); 
                    </script>

                    <input id="SaveImage" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Sauvegarder l'image" />
                    <input id="SaveNoImage" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Aucune photo" />
                </div>  
            }
```

I will not post the controller code since it just get inside in the cases where the file upload is empty.

Any idea what is going wrong?
Thanks

***VERY IMPORTANT EDIT***

Today I decided to go back in my SVN history and try to see what happend. I discovered something very weird. If I want it to work, I NEED to include the jquery in the view itself (Create.cshtml). I always though that to include the jquery .js file in the _layout.cshtml was enougth but it isn't! So only by doing this, it works in Chrome.

I still have a bug in Internet Explorer that prevent the image from displaying because the event on the "load" of the iframe launch this: "Runtime Error Microsoft JScript: Access denied". It works perfectly in Chrome.  Any idea???

***EDIT 2***

It was asked in the comments to add the code in jsfiddle. I'm not too sure how it work so I copy the rendered html, cut the javascript and put it in the javascript windows. It doesn't do anything right now, I'm not sure why but at least you can see the whole picture. Hope it helps. (Note that I did some modification compare to the code in the question but the problem is the same). [here!](http://jsfiddle.net/DarkJaff/74eHu/)

Comment: Have you tried sending data "by hand" with a classic ajax call? Have you also checked that you do not get a 404 after submitting a file. Which means that your action is not correctly signed?

Comment: no I did not try. I used this method and it worked well at first. In the original article that I followed, instead of using the submit event, it was calling a function who did a .submit at the end. Unfortunatly, this is not supported in IE9. So, the workaround was to use the event but something strange prevent the submit to finish when there is an image...

Comment: try return false instead of true?

Comment: Are you refreshing parts of your page at any point with Jquery?  I had lots of problems binding events using "on", as the event bindings will be lost as soon as any part of the html is refreshed. I and ended up going with the ".live("click", function ()" style event bindings instead which don't suffer this problem.

Comment: Doesn't work. It does the same thing. It goes in the submit function itself, do all the work but it never really submit the form because the jquery ready code is never called again.

Comment: Does the jQuery make it to the `return true` in the case of a file is selected?

Comment: If it gets inside the controller when it's empty, but not when a file is selected, then my guess is that the file submit button isn't working.  Have you tried just using one submit button and distinguishing between the different scenarios in the JQuery block instead?

Comment: @JeremyBoyd: yes it make it to the return true. Also, please see the important update. I now only have an "Access Denied" error.

Comment: Can you make [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with (rendered) view containing form `ImgForm`?

Comment: I will try tonight... I never try it before.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté is the `ImgForm` inside the `IFrame`?

Comment: I don't know whether this will work but you can use this on button click event 
javascript:document.getElementById('imagefile').click(); to get the image and then paste the image on the div where you want the image to show.  Then in the view, use file reader to read the image and use controller to get the byte [] image. I think there’s a function somewhere in jquery where we can set the attr of a div to target type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues here:

1. js ref in _layout is sufficient, however, you are referencing $ inline before jQuery is loaded.  Move all your script to the end and wrap in `$(document).ready(function ({ });`  then you can remove the duplicate js reference
2. you declare `var fileUploader` twice in the same block - dangerous, rename one of them
3. you never declare loadingImg, so the line `loadingImg = new Image();` is using an implicitly declared global - again dangerous if it doesn't exist (can't tell without complete code)
4. Once you fix these, you'll see that your form should never post back to the server because you are handling the submit client-side (in jQuery).

With these issues fixed, I get the same behavior in Chrome, FF, IE9 and IE10.  Here's the view I used:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                new
                {
                    enctype = "multipart/form-data",
                    id = "ImgForm",
                    name = "ImgForm",
                    target = "UploadTarget"
                }))
            {
                <div id="fileuploader">
                    <h4>Étape 1: Choisir une photo</h4>
                    <input id="lefile" type="file" style="display:none" name="imageFile" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" />
                    <div class="input-append">
                       <input id="photoCover" class="input-large" type="text" />
                       <a class="btn" onclick="$('input[id=lefile]').click();">Parcourir...</a>
                    </div>
                    <input id="SaveImage" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Sauvegarder l'image" />
                    <input id="SaveNoImage" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Aucune photo" />
                </div>  
            }

<div id ="UploadTarget">upload target</div>
<div id="Images"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[id=lefile]').change(function () {
                debugger;
                $('#photoCover').val($(this).val());
            });

            $('#ImgForm').on('submit', function () {
                alert('in js submit');
                var fileUploader = document.getElementById("fileuploader");
                $(fileUploader).hide();

                var fileUploader1 = document.getElementById("informations");
                $(fileUploader1).show();

                //Create a new image and insert it into the Images div.  Just to be fancy, 
                //we're going to use a "FadeIn" effect from jQuery
                var imgDiv = document.getElementById("Images");
                var loadingImg = new Image();
                loadingImg.src = "/content/335.gif";

                //Hide the image before adding to the DOM
                $(loadingImg).hide();
                imgDiv.appendChild(loadingImg);
                //Now fade the image in
                $(loadingImg).fadeIn(500, null);
                debugger;
                return true;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for having taken the time to answer. You answer makes a lot of sense but it make me realised something I discovered 2 days ago: This code wasn't good, it was in part copy-pasted from a tutorial on file upload and like you said, it contains a lot of problem. So 2 days ago, I've decided to go with a new approach and find this project: https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3/tree/master/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3 and it work like a charm. I'll give you the bounty for your work! Thanks again.